# Flowtype: How to use compute method in Class

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I wanna visit the class property according the params as the following code:

```
class Commander {
  constructor() {}
  create() {}
  test() {}
  undo() {}
  redo() {}
  execute(...args): void {
    const command: string = args.slice(0);
    const rest: any[] = args.slice(1);
    this[command].apply(this, rest);
  }
}
```

But I got an error as below:

> Cannot get `this[command]` because an indexer property is missing in `Commander` [1](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbRYB2ATApgJ2gbwChpph5UIAXbAV2AvmwAoBKfAXyJO0zAsxfac+lAXg7FqGeKPHRu6aazGdMAD0zBqfRgDo9YbAHMIzAFzQAbvACW6fJwCQpchRJIUGc5WzXUh6AC80AbGOhAg1sD8AAzMANycxM6UcpiU5mgAngDaALqBwUYQYRFRjACM8YnQFAAW1hDZpMho6Lk6YAAOnSCZjHUNADSplFXEHGxAA).

More info you can see the [flowtype try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbRYB2ATApgJ2gbwChpph5UIAXbAV2AvmwAoBKfAXyJO0zAsxfac+lAXg7FqGeKPHRu6aazGdMAD0zBqfRgDo9YbAHMIzAFzQAbvACW6fJwCQpchRJIUGc5WzXUh6AC80AbGOhAg1sD8AAzMANycxM6UcpiU5mgAngDaALqBwUYQYRFRjACM8YnQFAAW1hDZpMho6Lk6YAAOnSCZjHUNADSplFXEHGxAA).

If I make some stupid things, and please let me know!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

> Thanks your answer, but I wanna the code keep tidy, and I found the another solve [Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbRYB2ATApgJ2gbwChpoASAa0wE8AuaCAF2wEtUBzAbiNIDcwQBXTLTSUuweKgbZ+wevGwAKAJT4AvmOyYw9TMrVcdDPXnXF+GeMdPRN6SypNdMAD0zB+OhQDofYbKwglWm54JnR8LgBIcUl6aHFkNHRaKRZWaABeaD8ArwgQJmBdAAYlTmJiGIYbTAZhVEoAbQBdTOz-CDyCooUARjKuYnoACyYIRoSUDGavMAAHOZBKBRGxgBoahgHidXUgA). But use the any keyword, make the check no sense about the static check. – Cin

If you use any keyword that is the same as just turning flow off for anything that touches that variable.

"If you want a way to opt-out of using the type checker, any is the way to do it. Using any is completely unsafe, and should be avoided whenever possible." from [Any](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/any/)

This is a safer way: ([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbRYB2ATApgJ2gbwChpoASAa0wE8AuaAImHlQgBdsBXYF+bO6AH3rBsmMC0x9Bdca0n12GeHLoj0SgNxFSANzAh2mWgAoAlNAC8APmiIAlgA9M6LcNHjT+AL5aZLD3m9iBTV-QOhVeFCtTEdgdndGZDR0ABpoADpMkVYTWm14W3R8LWIWAAtbCABtRJQMAF10sAAHZpBKI3LKtOyWE01ib08gA))

```
class Commander {
  $key: "create" | "test" | "undo" | "redo";
  $value: () => mixed
  constructor() {}
  create() {}
  test() {}
  undo() {}
  redo() {}
  execute(command, ...rest): void {
    this[command].apply(this, rest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Property_names) you're using could be any string, Flow thinks you're trying to use your [class instance as a map](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps). To get around this, you need to do some sort of checking of the `command` variable before calling the instance methods. Here's my suggested way how to do it:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbRYB2ATApgJ2gbwChpph5UIAXbAV2AvmwAoBKfAXyJO0zAsxfac+lAXg7FqGeKPHRu6aazGdMAD0zBqfRgDo9YbAHMIzAFzQAbvACW6fJwCQpchRJIUGc5WzXUh6AC80AbGOhAg1sD8AAzMANycxM6UcpiU5mgAngDaALqBwUYQYRFRjACM8YnQEADu1hTAABaMpMho6ErVSZCY0ABEwhT9pt3E0BRN1sVDOmAADvMgmYyT0wA0qZRV47vQAEbcYADWCXskvQOSCiNjxGvF1-Bzi8urUxCb3Ntn5wdHpzGwEu-Xk8FufwmHx0YJeSxWDy+aQoOz+hx4gPOWAAZmBqCAKKNIZNsPBatBUJhyQBRbCkpj9ACSqAsYAidjaHnQ-VRxFkHDYQA))

```
class Commander {
  constructor() {}
  create() {}
  test() {}
  undo() {}
  redo() {}
  execute(...args): void {
    const command: string = args.slice(0);
    const rest: any[] = args.slice(1);
    switch(command) {
      case "test":
        this.test.apply(this, rest);
        break;
      case "undo":
        this.undo.apply(this, rest);
        break;
      case "redo":
        this.redo.apply(this, rest);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error("Invalid command");
    }
  }
}
```

You could also replace the `method.apply(this, rest)` syntax with `method(...rest)` to keep things a little cleaner, but that's stylistic ands not very relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I wanna the code keep tidy, and I found the another solve [Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEDCD2BbRYB2ATApgJ2gbwChpoASAa0wE8AuaCAF2wEtUBzAbiNIDcwQBXTLTSUuweKgbZ+wevGwAKAJT4AvmOyYw9TMrVcdDPXnXF+GeMdPRN6SypNdMAD0zB+OhQDofYbKwglWm54JnR8LgBIcUl6aHFkNHRaKRZWaABeaD8ArwgQJmBdAAYlTmJiGIYbTAZhVEoAbQBdTOz-CDyCooUARjKuYnoACyYIRoSUDGavMAAHOZBKBRGxgBoahgHidXUgA). But use the `any` keyword, make the check no sense about the static check.